# why 2 times destructor called in this code?

Tags: c++, multithreading, class

sorry but I cant understand why 2 times destructor called?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class myClass
{
public:
    int integer;
    void operator()()
    {
        std::cout << "class: " << integer << "\t" << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
    }
    myClass(int h)
        : integer{h}
    {
    }
    ~myClass()
    {
        std::cout << "MyClass by int: " << integer << " destroyed!" << std::endl;
    }
};

bool myFunc(int x)
{
    myClass tempClass(x);
    std::thread one(tempClass);
    one.join();
    if (x <= 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return myFunc(x - 1);
}
int main()
{
    myFunc(10);
    return 0;
}
```

note : I'm just trying in MultiThreads. (training)
and one more problem is that why before joining thread , my class has destroyed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the line

```
std::thread one(tempClass);
```

a copy of `tempClass` is created. Later on, both instances of `myClass` are destroyed.

You can pass `tempClass` by reference by using `std::ref`, but then you have to guarantee that `tempClass` remains valid (e.g. does not go out of scope, is brought in an invalid state by the main thread) throughout the life time of your thread (`one`).

You can also move `tempClass` into the other thread. You would still end up with two destructor calls and it would hardly make any difference in your case, but if `myClass` is difficult to copy, it can make a difference. In that case, you may want to read up on move semantics.